# How to select TextEdit region with mouse

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2, textedit

I want to select a region of the text with the mouse.

```
TextEdit {
        id: edit
        anchors.fill: parent
        font.pixelSize: 18
        focus: true
        wrapMode: TextEdit.Wrap
        text: "bla bla"
    }
```

i can select with the keyboard and clicking with the mouse give focus, but i cannot select a region of text with the mouse.

is this possible. thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Found it!

```
selectByMouse: true
```

wasn't the default.